# Is "I wish I could write half as well as you can" correct?

Tags: comparative-constructions

I think I read a similar expression somewhere before, but Google is not helping me.

I'm looking for a sentence that means "I would be happy if I could write 50% as well as you can", does it make sense? Is there a better, idiomatic, alternative?

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is correct and means what you intended.